# I can not handle the null return of the find function

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, null

as announced in the title, I try to act according to the null doctrine response. However despite the dump which confirms the return of a null value, my code does not take it into account. Would you like what is the cause?
This is my code :

```
    public function getUserBATS(UserRepository $repository ,$email, ObjectManager $em): Collection
    {
        $user = $repository->findOneBy(array('email' => $email));
        dump($user);
        if($user != null) {
            $bats = $user->getBATS();
            return $bats;
        }
        else
        { return $message = 'email don't...';}
    }
```

[Symfony response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/45fNM.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do something like this cause your function return a Collection and not a string:

```
public function getUserBATS(UserRepository $repository ,$email, ObjectManager $em): Collection
{
    $user = $repository->findOneBy(array('email' => $email));
    if($user !== null) {
        return $user->getBATS();
    }
    throw new NotFoundHttpException('user not found');
}
```

Comment: It is fine thanks ! But user side will there be a rendering? if the console is display, apart from a developer, he will not know what to do right?

Comment: It's depend who your use your function, if you call it from a controller you can put it into a try catch to do something if user is not found. You can also throw a NotFoundHttpException in a controller this will show a 404 page error in production, you can custom errors pages (doc: https://symfony.com/doc/current/controller/error_pages.html)